# Trying to figure out how to make a simple network game Need some help

Tags: java, tcp

I'm writing a simple card reading game.
The idea is that the server will start at game board position 1.  Then it will wait until it gets a HTTP message from all the players or a time out.  The reply will be for the information of the current board position.  Thus if a client ends up sending 2 messages, it will get two replies with the same game bored id.

Each time it get a connection from a client, a thread will be sent out to process the message and it will wait for the next connection.

PROBLEM: the messages are process on a serpent thread.  If all the players have replied with a message.  What would be the best way to tell the main thread to go to the next board pos?? Maybe I would just have to make it single thread? But then I'm afraid that a bug could freeze the server.

Then there is the issue of the time out.

One idea I had was to set a timeout on the socket, so if no connection was made, it would always exit, and then could check for a time out or if all the players have sent a message.

This is my first attempt at a network game, I'm assuming there are a lot of ways to do this.

Ted

Comment: ever heard of a semaphore? if you haven't I wouldn't go any further with multithreading until you know what it is and how to use it.

Comment: `the messages are process on a serpent thread.` The problem is that you're using a serpent thread, which is known to be extreamely dangerous when pro/invoked. Without formal training, I would stick with threads in the .NET kingdom. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is have a main `Server` class, with a thread for each client. The thread is added to an `ArrayList` of `Threads` representing each client.

You can then have the `Server` class iterate over the list and check for a value, such as `hasMessage`. If each one is true, then continue the game.

Here is some cheap code that does it:

```
//...Somewhere in the Server
ArrayList<Thread> clients = new ArrayList<Thread>();

public void addClient() {
  clients.add(new ClientThread());
}

public boolean checkForMessages() {
  for(Thread t : clients)
    if(!t.hasMessage)
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

The `ClientThread` class handles talking to each client, with each one on its own thread.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for your help, I heard of other people using arrays to store each client object in other message boards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ~code that might help.

```
// use an atomic integer so all threads can count their moves
AtomicInteger moveCounter = new AtomicInteger();

// main thread is in a loop
long timeoutMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + MOVE_TIMEOUT_MILLIS;
while (moveCounter.get() < NUMBER_OF_CLIENTS) {
    synchronized (moveCounter) {
        // wait a second
        moveCounter.wait(timeoutMillis - System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= timeoutMillis) {
        // we timed out, break
        break;
    }
}
// now go ahead and process the move ...
```

Each client handler would do:

```
// read the move from the client ...
// store the move somewhere in the server...
moveCounter.decrementAndGet();
// exit
```

You probably should be using the `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` or another one of the thread pools to fork a handler for each of your client connections.

Hope this helps.